# Notice: Undefined variable with <?= $property

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am trying to change this little piece of code to get the notice away.

Normally I fix this with if(isset(), but that doesn't work here.

The field won't load the property from the previous page when using if(isset().

Also when I change this the function won't work.

```
<?= change to <?php
```

I am stuck now. Don't know how to solve this.

Does anyone know how to solve this notice?

```
Notice: Undefined variable: one

<input type="text" name="one" value="<?= $one; ?>" placeholder="example" />
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to contain the answer. Simply [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the correct answer. Please refer to the [help] for further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dosent work for you?

```
<input type="text" name="one" value="<?php if(isset($one)) { echo $one; }; ?>" placeholder="example" />
```

Comment: Great :) Your question was a bit hard to understand. That might be why you got some down votes.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Tried to explain it the best way I could. :) I can't give a +1. Don't have enough reputation yet. Thank you again. I've been struggeling a long time to find and try to fix it by trial and error.

Comment: @user3340571: If this answer helped solving your problem, you can click on the green tickmark below the question's score to accept it as correct.

Comment: I know. But the script on stackoverflow says that I have to wait 3 minutes before the tickmark works. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="one" value="<?php
           if ( isset($_GET['one']) ) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['one']) ?>    
 placeholder="example" />
```